# markdown translator that can put boxes around code snippets

Tags: markdown

I want to write blog posts with markdown. The posts will include code snippets.
I like the way github renders these files. Especially that code snippets are surrounded by boxes distinguishing them better from the rest of the text.
I tried some markdown translators but found no option of doing this in any of them.
Is their a translator which is able to do this?

Thanks
Nathan

Comment: What kind of blog-engine are you using? Which aspects of the Github code-layout do you wish to reproduce? Just the box? or also line numbers, syntax highlighting and so on?

Comment: I am posting on blogger. Syntax highlighting does pandoc already provide. But I want the code blocks to have a box around them. CSS as in the selected answer works very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markdown usually produces HTML pure HTML as output. 
Specifically a Markdown Code-Block will be translated into `<pre><code>…</code></pre>` tags.
Without specific styling these blocks are displayed as defined in the browser stylesheet.

To show these tags in a box, you can style them with CSS the way you want (e.g. with `border`).